# Copy and Paste a Range of Cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a cells in the column C5:C27 and paste them in the range L5:L27, but I keep getting a Run-time error '1004':

This selection is not valid. There are several possible reasons: 
1. Copy and paste areas cannot overlap unless they are the same size and shape. 
2. If you are using the Create from Selection command, the row or column containing the proposed names will not be included in the...

That is all the message box shows. Every row of the column C5:C27 is only partially filled, could that be the problem here? Is there any other method that I might use to cut and paste in VBA? 
Thanks a bunch.

```
Sub CopyColumn()
    ' Cut and Paste date column
    Worksheets("TankHours").Activate
    Dim TimeCol As Range

    Set TimeCol = Range("C5:C27")
    TimeCol.Cut
    TimeCol.Insert Range("L5:L27")

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just copying and pasting I would do like this.

```
Sub CopyColumn()

  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L5:L27").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C27").Value

End Sub
```

One range equals another range.